# Why are the bottoms of the bowls of my p's and q's in this Typekit font getting cut off?

Tags: css, webfonts, typography, text-rendering, typekit

Using a webfont (Tablet Gothic from Typekit/Adobe Fonts) for a project at work, we noticed that on Windows and Linux machines, regardless of browser, the bottom bit of the bowls on the p's and q's are getting cut off, while the descenders remain intact. Using a thicker variant of the font doesn't eliminate the problem, only makes it marginally less obvious.

image 1.

[image]

image 2.

[image]

(these are screenshots from TeamViewer, please excuse the graininess)

My boss is hesitant to let me post links to our dev sites on here, but if the image doesn't cut it for explanation, I'll convince her to let it slide and post the link. I'd try to emulate it here w/ code but I can't seem to reproduce it literally anywhere.

I've tried to fix it with `-webkit-font-smoothing`, `text-rendering`, `line-height` stuff, increasing the weight and the size, but the best I've been able to get is letters with intact counters but with flat outer bottoms.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Our client really loved the type choices here but if this can't be fixed it might be a dealbreaker.

Edit: here's a reproduction that's probably only visible on Windows and Linux machines:

Edit2: confirmed that this example suffers the same problem on non-macOS machines.

```css
h2 {
    font-family: "tablet-gothic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #005556;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <!-- General meta tags needed-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <!-- Needed for responsive design -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Hinson & Hale Medical Technologies</title>

  <!-- Adobe Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/vbf4dsu.css">

  <!-- FontAwesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/914ac9a7cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>FDA-Approved</h2>
  <h2>Frequently</h2>
  <h2>ppppppppp</h2>
  <h2>qqqqqqqqq</h2>

</body>
```

Comment: If you aren't able to reproduce it then we won't be able to either. Until you can come up with a [mcve] to post here, within your question, there is no way we can help except to make wild guesses. And that will just get your question closed (which will probably happen soon anyway).

Comment: looks like it is about `font-weight: 300;` . You may want to use : Tablet Gothic Thin or Tablet Gothic Light instead.

Comment: @G-Cyr ```font-weight: 300``` is equivalent to Tablet Gothic Light.

Comment: @CalebPeters okay, but was it loaded/purchased too ? your snippet demonstrate your issue to me, but not https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/type-together/tablet-gothic/ there

Comment: @G-Cyr every weight between Light and Bold has been loaded via the Typekit web kit. It's not purchased—my boss won't shell out $800 for it. The only thing paid for is the Typekit subscription through Creative Cloud.

Comment: okay, i have no idea, text-shadow, text-rendering,font-smooth or any other i could think of seems to be efficient here. Hope you come up with an answser .